# Perform an input check and initialise an object in C++

Tags: c++, object, if-statement

I have an example code for asking the user for making an animal by user input but the check is in the if-else construction and the compiler gives me error "error: 'animal' was not declared in the scope". Here is my code. Please suggest how can I work it around.

```
class Animal{
public:
    string getName(){
        return myName;
    }
     void setName(string name){
        myName = name;
    }
    virtual string Sound()
    {

    }
private:
    string myName;
};
class Cat : public Animal{
public:
    string Sound(){
        return "Myau!\n";
    }
};
class Dog : public Animal{
public:
    string Sound(){
        return "Bark!\n";
    }
};
int main() {

    string type, name;
    cout<<"Vyvedete jivotno:\n 1. Cat\n2. Dog\nJivotno:";
    cin>>type;
    cout<<"\nVyvedete ime:";
    cin>>name;
    if(type == "Cat")
    {
        Cat animal;
    }
    else if(type == "Dog")
    {
        Dog animal;
    }

    animal.setName(name);
    cout<<"My name is "<<animal.getName()<<endl;
    cout<<animal.Sound()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your animal is declared inside if statement, no animal outside if statement.

Comment: The `Cat` and `Dog` you create are destroyed after the scope you created them in ends.

Comment: What is the lifetime of those `Cat` and `Dog` objects?  You also don't need all of this code to see the issue:  `int main() { int i = 10; { int x = 20; } x = 4; }` -- The `x` is no longer valid at the `x = 4;` line of code.

Comment: Cat animal is declared inside the if {} block so it only lives there.  Dog animal is a separate object declared in the else if {} block so it only lives there.  After the if {} else if {}, both of these are out of scope.

Comment: Remember `local` variables are visible to their scope so outside they are not available.

Comment: I think you might be coming from a language like Javascript.  In C/C++, if you have something like this {int x; DoSomething(x); }, the variable x is declared inside the scope bounded by the curly braces.  It is destroyed once code flows out of this scope.  To fix your sample, you will have to declare animal in the outer scope, above the if {} else if {}.

Comment: Additionally `Sound` function must return a value in the `Animal` class as well. Just because you don't know what does generic animal say doesn't mean you should not return anything. I suggest "Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow! Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow! Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!"

Answer (score 1):

```
Cat animal;
```

Creates a `Cat` object locally in this scope `if (type == "Cat") { ... }`. And you can't make something like other languages.

```
Animal animal;

if (type == "Cat") {
    animal = Cat();
}
```

This creates a `Cat` object, and COPIES it into the `Animal` object, it is sometimes called **"Slicing"** where you copied just a part of `Cat` object.

How it works?

`Animal` has an implicitly generated copy constructor like that

```
Animal(const Animal &original) {
   // Copies here
}
```

So, copying Cat into animal, is just that the `original` is treated as if it is an `Animal` only, and this is copied.

If you try to make references, it will not work, why?

```
Animal &animal;
```

Now, this object is NOT initialized (no null references are allowed).

And if you try doing something like that:

```
Animal &animal = Animal();
```

You couldn't because `Animal()` is a temporary object (can't be referenced by a normal reference (called in C++11: `lvalue-reference`)).

"temporary objects" are not to be confused with "local objects", temporary objects are what generated by expression like that `Cat()`. But local object is anything inside a scope.

And, trying to do something like that:

```
Animal source;

Animal &animal = source;

if(type == "Cat")
{
    Cat catSource;
    animal = catSource;
}
else if(type == "Dog")
{
    Dog dogSource;
    animal = dogSource;
}
```

It will try to use the `copy assignment` which is like copy constructor but for an existant object (so also slicing happens).

---

So, your solution is to make a pointer (in C++, use smart pointers to be managed automatically for you), not local object.

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal;

if (type == "Cat") {
    animal = std::unique_ptr(new Animal());
}
```

Then treat `animal` as a pointer, not an object.

Use `->`, instead of `.`

```
unique_ptr<Animal> animal;

if(type == "Cat")
{
    animal = unique_ptr<Animal>(new Cat());
}
else if(type == "Dog")
{
    animal = unique_ptr<Animal>(new Dog());
}

animal->setName(name);
cout<<"My name is "<<animal->getName()<<endl;
cout<<animal->Sound()<<endl;
```